# Gnuplot: replot inside do for

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

Of 3 versions of replotting only 2 work as desired:

```
plot sin(x)
replot sin(x)/2
replot sin(x)/3
replot sin(x)/4
```

After each command the respective curve is added to the plot - as expected.

```
plot sin(x)
replot for [i=2:4] sin(x)/i
```

gives the same (final) result (4 curves in the plot), but

```
plot sin(x)
do for [i=2:4] {replot sin(x)/i}
```

results in a plot with only the 1st and the 4th curve, although 4 lines are written in the key. Is this a "feature" or (how) can I get 4 curves in the do-for-version (because I have to do some additional stuff within the do-clause)?

[gnuplot 5.2 (8), Ubuntu MATE 20.04]

Comment: You could plot all 4 curves like this `plot for [i=1:4] sin(x)/i`. What else do you have to do inbetween why you need a `do for` loop?

Comment: Besides some other stuff (calculations using 'i') I want to - said very simplified - also draw cos(x)/i. Using "replot  for [i=2:4] sin(x)/i ; replot  for [i=2:4] cos(x)/i" yields the wrong order, because I want sin(x), cos(x), sin(x)/2, cos(x/2, ...

Comment: actually with your last example, 3 curves of `sin(x)/4` will be on top of each other. If you type `show plot` in the gnuplot console you will get `last plot command was: plot sin(x), sin(x)/i, sin(x)/i, sin(x)/i` and for the last `replot` command `i=4`. I guess that's the way `replot` works. It will not plot `sin(x), sin(x)/2, sin(x)/3, sin(x)/4`.

Comment: if the order is important, e.g. with your alternating sin(x), cos(x) example, you could use: `plot for [i=1:4] for [b=0:1] b?sin(x)/i:cos(x)/i title sprintf("%s(x)/%d",b?'sin':'cos',i)`. But maybe you edit the question and describe your final goal in more detail.

Comment: "I guess that's the way replot works." - looks like that, yes. So I found a solution (which I will post in a few seconds) with creating a macro.  (Although this is not so nice in my real problem as it looks in this simple example here.)

Comment: the better you can describe your real problem, the better we could possibly help you... ;-)

Comment: "if the order is important ... you could use" - oh, that's also a nice one, thanks!

Comment: "the better you can describe your real problem, the better we could possibly help you... ;-)" - My real problem is not about `sin` and `cos` but a big data-file with nearly hundred columns of data, for each of the 16 curves I want to draw (in a special order) 5-7 of the columns have to be combined (calculations involving i to get the right column-number), ... But my main interest here was not the solution for my specific problem but to understand or recognise the behaviour of `gnuplot` and `replot`.

Comment: I was trying to do some complex calculations and the only way to do replot inside a do-for is using a macro as suggested by  @SandwichX answer. His answer should be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax that expresses what you were originally trying to do is this:

```
do for [i=1:4] {
    # ... do some stuff ...  #
    plot for [j=1:i] sin(x)/j title sprintf("sin(x)/%d",j)
}
```

`replot` is really not what you want for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

So a way to use `replot` inside a do-for-loop is creating a macro:

```
plot sin(x), cos(x)
txt = ""
do for [i=2:4] {
  # some calculations involving i
  txt = txt . "replot sin(x)/" . i . ", cos(x)/" . i . " ; "
  # maybe some more stuff involving i
}
@txt
```

Comment: ok, fine... but where is the "additional stuff you need to do within the do-for loop"? You'll get the same using the code I posted in the comments above...

Comment: I edited my answer and added the "additional stuff".

Comment: if you want to see the 'txt' command that will be executed
`print txt`

Answer (score 1):

#### Additioal Way

There is also a way to use the `eval` command in loop, as follows.

```
plot sin(x), cos(x)
do for [i=2:4] {
  # some calculations involving i
  command = sprintf("replot sin(x)/%i, cos(x)/%i", i, i)
  eval command
  # maybe some more stuff involving i
}
```

Comment: That's a feasible approach to get the right numbers into `i`. Ha, I remember probably my first question on StackOveflow was about using `eval` in Python and I got 5 downvotes because they said "Never ever use `eval()`. Eval is evil. Well, ...